# Android stopped package recovering from app crash

Tags: android, service, google-cloud-messaging, crash

I am working on a multi-process, enterprise VOIP application that needs to remain running under all circumstances.  With that said, we all know that applications can crash and there are a number of crash recovery options so that my end-users aren't impacted (miss phone calls).

I have done a fair amount of research and testing on all of my options to guard against application crashes/force stopping by the user, etc, and have determined the following:

**STOPPED APPLICATIONS**

In Android 3.1, the concept of a stopped application package was introduced.  Android only defines two situations in which your application package is in a "stopped" state:

> Applications are in a stopped state when they are first installed but are not yet launched and when they are manually stopped by the user (in Manage Applications).
>   http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html

Notice that this doesn't specify app crashes and how they behave.

**GCM**

On devices that support it, I have the luxury of being able to rely on GCM from Google in order to reliably start my app in the case of an app crash.  This is done via the manifest by specifying a receiver:

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".receiver.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

This seems to be 100% reliable, and if I trigger a crash in my app, ends up re-launching my main process even after multiple crashes.

**Service START_STICKY**

Unfortunately I need to support a device that doesn't have Play Services installed and I can't rely on GCM for this device.  In this case, I have returned Service.START_STICKY from onSTartComment of my Service.  Per Android doc, this response specifies that:

> Constant to return from onStartCommand(Intent, int, int): if this service's process is killed while it is started (after returning from onStartCommand(Intent, int, int)), then leave it in the started state but don't retain this delivered intent. Later the system will try to re-create the service. 
>   http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY

This partially helps me, as when I trigger a crash within my app, the OS will re-start my app after some unknown time (usually within 20 seconds or so).  However, **it appears that it will only restart my app one time, and after subsequent crashes my app is NOT restarted.**  Whatever threshold it us using, doesn't seem be documented anywhere but I'd guess it's in place to prevent constantly crashing apps from running over and over again.  What are the details on this?

**Watchdog timer**
My last attempt at solving my problem was to create a watchdog timer that would trigger the same receiver as listed for GCM above.  Since I already have a service running in a separate process, I figured I could detect crashes in the main app, and schedule a broadcast to the receiver registered in my manifest and solve my problem.

The code executed from the service after an app crash:

```
                final Handler handler = new Handler();
            Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sending broadcast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intentNew = new Intent("GCMBroadcast");
                    intentNew.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
                    sendBroadcast(intentNew);
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 10000);
                }
            };
            handler.postDelayed(r, 10000);
```

And defined in my manifest for the receiver:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="GCMBroadcast"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

You'll notice I am even specifying the flag to include stopped packages.  This code works correctly **after the first crash**, my receiver is triggered, and my main process is brought back to life.  However, just like above, after the second crash my app is dead.  From log statements in my receiver, and the toast presented from sending the watchdog intent, I know the intent is continuing to be sent, and the receiver simply doesn't receive the broadcast after the second crash.

**My questions**
Is there anything I am doing wrong above?  Obviously the first priority is to eliminate crashes from my application, but is there any other fallback that I can rely on?

Does Android put "bad" applications in a stopped state if they are commonly crashing?  And if so, what are these thresholds?  If it isn't something I can code around, I at least need to document the impact on my application.  Obviously when I'm triggering crashes in my app to test this workflow, I am crashing 2 times within 30 seconds or so.

What is the actual intent of FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES?  It doesn't appear to actually help me in this situation, and I don't think it will have any impact for applications that were just installed but haven't been launched by the user yet anyways.

Again, this is a mission critical application with services that need to be running and connected regardless of what app crashes occur.

Comment: I've been facing the same problem. Were you able to figure out the solution or at least the documentation around the thresholds ?